# Django jsonfield, is it possible to filter with json array value length?

Tags: django, jsonfield

Suppose I have a jsonfield with data

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Foo(models.Model):
   json_field = JSONField(default=dict)

json_field = {
  'bar': [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I'd like to filter data where `bar` has array length greather than 3

Something like the following, `Foo.objects.filter(json_field__bar__length__gt=3)`

Comment: Please share you model class before, It possible to do what you espected

Comment: I just did. @NathanIngram

Comment: Yes create one more field in your model class inside it set every time lenght of you json_field... Please take a look of @Ajay Lingayat answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Create one more field in the model i.e `json_field_bar_length`.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ....
    json_field_bar_length = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And enter the length of `json_field['bar']` into it whenever you save the json_field in it and check if the length is greater or not.